# ERROR: Could not build wheels for spacy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects occurs while installing requirement.txt

Tags: python, spacy, python-venv

I am trying to install a github project but while installing the requirements,all the libraries are downloaded except the spacy.

```
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in e:\ai-resume-analyzer\app\venvapp\lib\site-packages (from spacy==2.3.5->-r requirements.txt (line 73)) (65.5.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: spacy
  Building wheel for spacy (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for spacy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1118 lines of output]
      .
      .
      .
      Generating code
      Finished generating code
      building 'spacy.strings' extension
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\vatsh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ezxsrk4b\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include" -IC:\Users\vatsh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8uacba_l\spacy_c54e976fe0ff449bb1ffd83dee7fe8c0\include -IE:\AI-Resume-Analyzer\App\venvapp\include "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include" "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /Tpspacy/strings.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\spacy/strings.obj /Ox /EHsc
      strings.cpp
      spacy/strings.cpp(2153): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
      spacy/strings.cpp(2228): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
      spacy/strings.cpp(2769): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'long' to 'unsigned char', possible loss of data
      spacy/strings.cpp(3292): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
      spacy/strings.cpp(3863): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
      spacy/strings.cpp(3874): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
      spacy/strings.cpp(4265): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
      spacy/strings.cpp(4280): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
      spacy/strings.cpp(5923): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
      spacy/strings.cpp(10123): error C3861: '_PyGen_Send': identifier not found
      spacy/strings.cpp(10128): error C3861: '_PyGen_Send': identifier not found
      spacy/strings.cpp(10212): error C3861: '_PyGen_Send': identifier not found
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for spacy
Failed to build spacy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for spacy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I was just installing the requirements but everytime this problem arises.
Python version 3.9.13
I have cut the dialog because it only allows 30000 character.

Answer (score 0):

If this requires spacy v2.3, then one easy option is to relax the constraint to `spacy~=2.3.5` and then there are wheels for newer patch releases for newer versions of python.

If you only want to install v2.3.5, then you can either:

- Use an older version of python (up to python 3.9)
- Compile from the git repo source instead of from the pypi sdist

  The pypi sdist was released before this version of python was published and some generated cython code is not compatible. You can install from the git repo source instead and it should regenerate compatible cython:

  ```bash
  pip install git+https://github.com/explosion/spaCy@v2.3.5
  ```